# Using const assertions, how can I extract the literal types from nested objects?

Tags: typescript, types

Suppose I have the following object:

```js
const kids = {
  Karen: ['Ava', 'Emma'],
  Mary: ['Sophia'],
} as const;
```

By using [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) I can extract the literal types with:

```js
type Mother = keyof typeof kids; // Karen|Mary
type Kid = typeof kids[Mother][number]; // Ava|Emma|Sophia
```

Now suppose the following object, which is one level deeper:

```js
const grandkids = {
  Karen: {
    Ava: ['Alice', 'Amelia'],
    Emma: ['Sarah'],
  },
  Mary: {
    Sophia: ['Grace'],
  },
} as const;
```

I'm able extract the first level with:

```js
type Grandmother = keyof typeof grandkids; // Karen|Mary
```

But how can I extract the literals for `Mother` (Karen, Mary) and `Kid` (Alice, Amelia, Sarah, Grace)?

Comment: What type do you expect?

Comment: Are you looking for something that works for arbitrary depths? If so then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wk8alw) meet your needs?  I could write up an answer explaining if that works for you; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Your solution works, but Florent's answer is easier to grasp. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you *don't* need something that works for arbitrary depths, right?

Comment: @jcalz Although my specific user case ends and this depth, your example made me interested in a solution for N arbitrary depths, yes.

Comment: But you've already accepted an answer that only works for a depth of 2, so you're not looking for an arbitrary depth solution *in this question*, right?  I just want to make sure that this question is answered and I can disengage from it. If you want to see an arbitrary depth solution you could post a new question, I suppose.

Comment: @jcalz Indeed, this is another question. I just created it, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76289908

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really just want to extract each literals, you can do something like this :

```
const grandkids = {
  Karen: {
    Ava: ['Alice', 'Amelia'],
    Emma: ['Sarah'],
  },
  Mary: {
    Sophia: ['Grace'],
  },
} as const;

type Grandmother = keyof typeof grandkids;

type Mother = {
  [K in Grandmother]: keyof typeof grandkids[K];
}[Grandmother];

type Kid = {
  [K in Grandmother]: {
    [M in Mother]: typeof grandkids[K][M extends keyof typeof grandkids[K] ? M : never];
  };
}[Grandmother][Mother][number];
```

For `Mother`, we just have to extract the keys of each attribute of `grandkids`

For `Kid` we extract the arrays for each mother inside each grandmother, and flat all the arrays with `[number]`

This condition

```
M extends keyof typeof grandkids[K] ? M : never
```

is important because at this point M can be a key of 'Karen' or 'Mary', so typescript won't let us use `M` to index `grandkids[K]` because it cannot be sure that `M` is a key of `grandkids[K]`.

Hope this helps

Comment: This worked perfectly. I'll need some time to wrap my head around this syntax though (reminds me of C++ templates). Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help ! Don't hesitate if you need further explanation