# Using const assertions, how can I extract the literal types from arbitrarily nested objects?

Tags: typescript, types

This question is a follow up to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76288737/6923555), where I had a structure which has a depth of 2:

```js
const grandkids = {
  Karen: {
    Ava: ['Alice', 'Amelia'],
    Emma: ['Sarah'],
  },
  Mary: {
    Sophia: ['Grace'],
  },
} as const;
```

For the example above, I can extract the literal types with:

```js
type Grandmother = keyof typeof grandkids; // Karen|Mary

type Mother = {
  [K in Grandmother]: keyof typeof grandkids[K];
}[Grandmother]; // Ava|Emma|Sophia

type Kid = {
  [K in Grandmother]: {
    [M in Mother]: typeof grandkids[K][M extends keyof typeof grandkids[K] ? M : never];
  };
}[Grandmother][Mother][number]; // Alice|Amelia|Sarah|Grace
```

But what if I have a structure with 3 levels?

```js
const greatgrandkids = {
  Beth: {
    Karen: {
      Ava: ['Alice', 'Amelia'],
      Emma: ['Sarah'],
    },
    Mary: {
      Sophia: ['Grace'],
    },
  },
  Ruth: {
    Ella: {
      Scarlett: ['Charlotte'],
    },
  },
};
```

For the structure above, with also has a grandgrandmother, we have an additional type, which is the first level:

```js
type GreatGrandmother = /* CODE?? */; // Beth|Ruth
type Grandmother = /* ... */; // Karen|Mary|Ella
type Mother = // ...
```

And the example goes on, for an arbitrary number of levels. Consider uniform deepness, with complete levels up to the leaf fields.

Comment: Add the necessary context to your question so that it's answerable even if the question you linked would get removed or altered.

Comment: Please [edit] the example to show various levels and what your expected outputs are, so that nobody needs to look at the other question to understand it, and to know what use cases you need to cover.  What about trees that aren't uniformly deep, like `{a: ["z"], b: {c: ["y", "x"]}}`? Do you need those?  Do you want the depth to be an input to the type, like `StringLiteralsAtDepth<typeof grandkids, 2>`?  A good [mre] would help here.

Comment: I edited the question to be more comprehensive. I'm unsure of the input type, your suggestion looks good to me.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m0x7rm) work for you?  Your question is a bit of a hybrid thing, since for most of the levels you're looking for keys and then suddenly at the bottom you're looking for values.  It might be better if you [edit]ed this to be a single uniform data structure as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wExgbW).  Let me know how you want to proceed.

Comment: Yes, this approach works perfectly. Make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most of that structure you're looking for the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) corresponding to the keys at some fixed depth.  So we can write a utility type `KeysAtDepth<T, N>` so that, say, `KeysAtDepth<T, 0>` corresponds to the keys of `T` directly, and `KeysAtDepth<T, 1>` corresponds to the keys of all the properties of `T`, and `KeysAtDepth<T, 2>` corresponds to the keys of all the sub-properties of `T`, etc.

Here's one way to write that:

```
type KeysAtDepth<T, N extends number, A extends any[] = []> =
  T extends unknown ? (
    N extends A['length'] ? keyof T : KeysAtDepth<T[keyof T], N, [0, ...A]>
  ) : never;
```

This is a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types).  TypeScript can't really do math with `number` types directly (see [microsoft/TypeScript#26382](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382)), but it *can* represent the operation of appending to [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) (via [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types)) and checking their `length` property, so we can encode "recurse until depth `N`" as "prepend an element to a tuple `A` every time we recurse and then stop when the `A['length']` is `N`".

The base case of the recursion is to just return `keyof T`; otherwise we apply `KeysAtDepth` to `T[keyof T]`, meaning the union of all the properties of `T`.

That explains most of what's going on there; the only part left is to explain is that  why we have `T extends unknown ? ⋯ : never`, which looks like it doesn't do anything. The reason is to make `KeysAtDepth<T, N>` a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) in `T`, so that `KeysAtDepth<A | B, N>` is equivalent to `KeysAtDepth<A, N> | KeysAtDepth<B, N>`.  Without that then you'd end up with things like `keyof (A | B)` which isn't what you want (it would only show you keys that exist in *all* members of the union).

---

Let's test it out:

```
const greatgrandkids = {
  Beth: {
    Karen: {
      Ava: ['Alice', 'Amelia'],
      Emma: ['Sarah'],
    },
    Mary: {
      Sophia: ['Grace'],
    },
  },
  Ruth: {
    Ella: {
      Scarlett: ['Charlotte'],
    },
  },
} as const;

type GreatGrandKids = typeof greatgrandkids;
type GreatGrandMother = KeysAtDepth<GreatGrandKids, 0>
// type GreatGrandMother = "Beth" | "Ruth"
type GrandMother = KeysAtDepth<GreatGrandKids, 1>
// type GrandMother = "Karen" | "Mary" | "Ella"
type Mother = KeysAtDepth<GreatGrandKids, 2>;
// type Mother = "Ava" | "Emma" | "Sophia" | "Scarlett"
```

So far, so good.

---

Ideally your `greatgrandkids` structure would be uniform and use keys the whole way down, like

```
const greatgrandkids = {
  Beth: {
    Karen: {
      Ava: { Alice: {}, Amelia: {} },
      Emma: { Sarah: {} }
    },
    Mary: {
      Sophia: { Grace: {} }
    },
  },
  Ruth: {
    Ella: {
      Scarlett: { Charlotte: {} }
    },
  },
} as const;
```

and then the final type would just be the keys at depth `3`:

```
type Child = KeysAtDepth<GreatGrandKids, 3>
// type Child = "Alice" | "Amelia" | "Sarah" | "Grace" | "Charlotte"
```

But it's not, so we need another utility type like `TypesAtDepth<T, N>` to grab the union of the *types* at a particular depth.  So `TypesAtDepth<T, 0>` would be `T`, and `TypesAtDepth<T, 1>` would be `T[keyof T]` (the union of types at depth 1), etc.

It's almost the same: the only difference is that the base case is `T` instead of `keyof T`:

```
type TypesAtDepth<T, N extends number, A extends any[] = []> = 
  T extends unknown ? (
    N extends A['length'] ? T : TypesAtDepth<T[keyof T], N, [0, ...A]>
  ) : never;
```

And now `TypesAtDepth<GreatGrandKids, 3>` is a union of the [readonly tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) containing the string literals, into which we can [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with `number` to get the union of the element types:

```
type Child = TypesAtDepth<GreatGrandKids, 3>[number]
// type Child = "Alice" | "Amelia" | "Sarah" | "Grace" | "Charlotte"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAIDStIGcCC4AitrgBYA8AKgDTwBy8sAHuLAHYAmq8DArgLYBGsATuXTU6jFvACGDSAG0AuvAC88OQD5FoePGLD6zVuwYBrBgHsA7g3gB+eAAoNmyjtGt00gOQAbRgHMC7+RtDFBMAMy14AC4kFAxsXAISaWDIMK1ZcgpyaQAGcgA6QvRZFQcASii2WAA3fgBuUEaQAGMTBlRweB8+WHFwbskmQwBLMSUAbwcAIVgCaMmQRyRxHoZ5hyX0avFoj3RPYebYd3J3dE5YA-EA0g3HAFFOTh3ldwBlFfF8G7uAX1vFo4ALIrSDrQFLN4maD4YYvDwAcT44iOPwh8H+DkxgIASuw5vAFkt7p5PC8iUt4G9mitvOBwLt3ABhfC0kz044ZP4AzTY34SVitdrgBogKBweBI3rgJGDRCjVhKcWwNLdaUDZgjFii5WSnp9WXMIHs-D8RQxNCYHB4IhSg3I5jyljkHKlEAAend8F1dplDqYxoIZqUACIZgQQ-AAD7wEN4iMQGAIQ0Bk3Bi1xa2JX0pp2ocgARjdnu9Sb1g0Dpr45pDiBWjEjMZDIL4kEbsZJZJDiYllfTyEt8RthBz-rz5AATCpRSXdX3q6GtuJ2yHHs8V1CYXCNzS+HTwN2wGKy8Qk5mEkQyE5aLoxBwePxBM49BIpHJzapzdoby54AZjOYlhWA4VA-i+bheL4-iBBE0SnnA57DsQyQhOExAZJQ2R5PAhT5MUajRAwNT1E0uossMnhMF+Z5WheI76n6coKuQADMKjSPevB8LIoCzmW5GUTW+yHLAK7nJc27RrGHzIvgK6ykcK4smyHKHqADDiBcqDQCiCAAKoMMMoQmHwnBvOAfDsM04DsD0hIOEKHRdAxGpDAq5oUpo4b4OClLLKsvl+fAS6BUFwUHEc8zYmFmjiVcUV3Es0VBWu5KJZSMlfAl6JJelyVLC2YL2TljibrCaUlUsCmwNlYW-HlPKOPl8Dxj5xV+Z2FVhdStKzAy7Uxcpe7svQtVBfVJXNcl-LiIKbQdKKDi6gOiGJFeoEiC+nGPsFz5iJIMjyEon5KN+m1iP+pgWNYdwbbergeN4DB+N8MEpGk2jRCttFIShqRoRhWTKNhuH4ZURG1Hwi2Aj6DG5u5SpJqqLn+lqqCipoZGwoJSjfUO2Zw2OzHwGxDh8RKAlUYuEWiVJIZxZJTaZXJdPVUprLDapTS-EAA)